# Spring : How to get Oauth2 token from Postman?

Tags: java, spring, oauth-2.0, spring-oauth2

I have created Oauth2 server following to this [spring-security-oauth-example](https://github.com/TechPrimers/spring-security-oauth-example/blob/master/spring-security-auth-server/src/main/java/com/techprimers/security/springsecurityauthserver/config/ResourceServerConfig.java). How can I get the Oauth2 token from Postman ?

This is the code for Resource Server and this is the code for 
[AuthorizationServerConfig.](https://github.com/TechPrimers/spring-security-oauth-example/blob/master/spring-security-auth-server/src/main/java/com/techprimers/security/springsecurityauthserver/config/AuthorizationServerConfig.java)

I want to understand how can I get the Oauth2 token for clientid = "ClientId" from Postman ? And what these below code signify:

```
public class AuthorizationServerConfig extends AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

    @Override
    public void configure(AuthorizationServerSecurityConfigurer security) throws Exception {

        security.tokenKeyAccess("permitAll()")
                .checkTokenAccess("isAuthenticated()");
    }

    public class ResourceServerConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {


        http.requestMatchers()
                .antMatchers("/login", "/oauth/authorize") //what does this do
```

application.properties has

```
 server.port=8081 
 server.context-path=/auth security.basic.enable=false
```

Comment: Do you have a clientID, secret key and other details ?

Comment: yes it's clearly mentioned in the link
AuthorizationServerConfig

Comment: Do you want only the process how to set oauth2 in the postman ? Is it ok, if I give you steps upto creating new access token option. The data should be filled by you.

Comment: yes and a bit of explanation too..how the code in Github would work...Thanks a lot for your time

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The steps to set up the OAuth 2.0 token in Postman.

1. Open Postman.
2. Create a new request. Click on "authorization" tab. Screenshot below :

[image]

3. Select `Type` of authentication as OAuth 2.0. Screenshot below :

[image]

4. Now, click on the "Get New Access Token". It will pop up to show this below :

[image]

5. Enter the desired details like Client ID, Client Secret, CallBack URL, Auth URL, Access Token URL etc.

So, I'm adding some helpful resources for you to understand the OAuth 2.0 Type.

1. **[The OAuth 2.0 Authorization Framework](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749) - This will give an idea what is OAuth 2.0 Authorization Framework?**

A screenshot from the above link : How the Oauth 2.0 Authorization Framework looks like.

[image]

2. **Some video lectures to understand it visually :**

   a. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NRU_KdUSjD4

   b. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Dbxzw0cpxBU

Comment: were u able to get access token using the code in Github?

Comment: @RahulRaj I have added the video of the code owner. He has published a video tutorial on this. Please checkout.

Comment: B can you just what is the responsibility of Autherisation server and Resource server?

Comment: Resource server keeps all the resources which needs to be protected. Based on the access token, it provides the protected resource. On the other hand, the authorization server gives an access token from resource owner through which you can get access to the protected resource from resource server

Comment: Suppose i am hitting an /api/hsbc/account and hsbc directs me for authentican to Google .then which is the server resource server here

Comment: The resource you are trying to access though the url `/api/hsbc/account` is kept on the resource server. Since, you didn't have the access token. So, It redirects to you to google to get the access token. I don't know what url you are using for resource server. If `/api/hsbc/account` is the actual url, then that is the resource server.